# Google app engine user login with Google acount doesn't work for java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I used followng code to authonticate users from Google account.I followed this [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingusers).

> ```
>     UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
>     User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
> ```

```
    if (user != null) {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, " + user.getNickname());
    } else {
        resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
    }
```

But it get output as follow.
 [image: like this].
 I need to login with Google acount but It doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. after it deply to server, It works.